# pseudo code in scss - use not to select everything except last child

Tags: css, sass

I am totally new to scss, and confuse about the :first in scss,

I have the index.html code as below,

```
<div class="col-1-of-2 test">
    <h3 class="heading-tertiary u-margin-bottom-small">You are going to fall in love with nature</h3>
    <p class="paragraph">asdasdasd</p>

    <h3 class="heading-tertiary u-margin-bottom-small">Live adventures like you never have before</h3>
    <p class="paragraph">asdsad</p>

    <h3 class="heading-tertiary u-margin-bottom-small">Live adventures like you never have before</h3>
    <p class="paragraph">asdsad</p>

    <a href="#" class="btn-text">Click</a>
</div>
```

I try to select every paragraph except the last one as follow, but it actually match all paragraph, can you tell me the reason?

```
.paragraph {
    &:not(:last-child) {
        border: 1px solid green;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you to Terry, I figure our that the element has to be the first child of its parent if we would like to use :first-child.

By checking the doc, first-of-type can select the first element among siblings based on its element type.

If we really need to use class name for selecting the first element, we should
1. Apply the style to all .paragraph elements (.paragraph {...})
2. Remove the style from the .paragraph elements except first one 
(.paragraph ~ .paragraph {...})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't: the CSS pseudo-selector `:last-child` does not work like that. The `:last-child` applies to the last child element in the parent element. In your case, since `.paragraph` is not a last child, it will not be selected. You want to use `:last-of-type` instead:

```css
.paragraph:not(:last-of-type) {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-1-of-2 test">
  <h3 class="heading-tertiary u-margin-bottom-small">You are going to fall in love with nature</h3>
  <p class="paragraph">asdasdasd</p>

  <h3 class="heading-tertiary u-margin-bottom-small">Live adventures like you never have before</h3>
  <p class="paragraph">asdsad</p>

  <h3 class="heading-tertiary u-margin-bottom-small">Live adventures like you never have before</h3>
  <p class="paragraph">asdsad</p>

  <a href="#" class="btn-text">Click</a>
</div>
```